# How to get current document uri in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I access current xml document uri in XSLT?

Comment: Which version of XSLT are you using?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972658/retrieve-xml-file-name-using-xslt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This cannot be done in pure XSLT 1.0** without writing your own extension function.

**In XSLT 2.0 (or XPath 2.0) one can use the standard XPath 2.0 function [document-uri()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-document-uri)**

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: No :)

You can't. The namespace URI is conceptually part of the element name and you can't use xsl:copy if you want to change the name.

Comment: I assume the downvote was related to the OP wanted the document's URI, not the XML Namespace URI. (Not the downvoter)