# Retrieve XML file name using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I retrieve the XML source file name using XSL 1.0 code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, there are two relevant functions: base-uri() and document-uri().

In XSLT 1.0, you have to pass the URL or filename as a parameter to the stylesheet, unless the processor offers extension functions for the purpose.

Comment: How it to make? My users open XML in the browser. How to make so that parameter it was transferred automatically?

Comment: @Bush: You can change the design, so that the user doesn't directly open an XML file in the browser, but some Javascript code invokes the transformation, passing to it the file URL as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

With Xalan there is the following, non-official function :

```
<xsl:value-of select="document-location()"/>
```

I use it on a transformation of a local file and it gives me the absolute path of the XML file being transformed. I found that function browsing the Xalan code, it is part of the class `FuncDoclocation`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but other people may still come upon this in looking for an answer.

The only way I know of to do this in XSLT 1.0 is to use a script function inside the XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:user="http://tempuri.org/msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"/>

<msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="user">
<![CDATA[
function getFilename(context){
  return context.nextNode.url;
}
]]>
</msxsl:script>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <INPUT>
  <filename><xsl:value-of select="user:getFilename(/)"/></filename>
  </INPUT>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will generate an XML output such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<INPUT xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:user="http://tempuri.org/msxsl">
<filename>file:///C:/XLST/My%20Test%20XML%20File.txt.xml</filename>
</INPUT>
```

In this case, I used a file named `C:/XLST/My Test XML File.txt`.

The `vb.net` code used for importing text files first converts that file into XML and appends the `.xml` extension to the source filename, and is then processed by the Transform.

This is why my filename ends in `.txt.xml`

Normal XLST string functions can then be used as needed to replace the `%20` with `' '` and perhaps only return the filename part and not the entire path and filename.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to obtain the name or path of the file being transformed by XSL. Due to the nature of XSL, the data being transformed might not be from a file, it might just be transforming a stream of data.