# How to run the <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::table)"></xsl:for-each-group> of xslt2.0 by using xalan

Tags: xslt, saxon, xalan

Actually I have two methods :
one is :  `document-location()` 
and other is  :

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::table)">
```

first method is supported to xalan but not saxon and second method is supported saxon but not xalan .

for this I have created two files for two methods . But I dont want to create two different files .Is there any method which works same as  in xalan?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. If you want to use Xalan, replace `xsl:for-each-group` with the Muenchian grouping method - see:http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: And now it's even less clear.

Comment: I need a template which will be the replacement of <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::table)"> in xalan

Comment: if I want ro run document-location() method using saxon. So what I need to modify in this function so that I can run this successfully on saxon.

Answer (score 0):

The `<xsl:for-each-group>` construct was introduced in XSLT 2.0, and Xalan only supports XSLT 1.0. If you need to do grouping in XSLT 1.0, you'll have to use the Muenchian grouping method. If there are things in your stylesheet that prevent you migrating from Xalan to Saxon to take advantage of XSLT 2.0 (and 3.0), then please tell us exactly what the issues are and we can probably help you with the migration. (That would be best done in a new question.)

Answer (score 0):

> I want ro run document-location() method using saxon.

I cannot find any documentation of what this method actually does.

If - as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25571206) - it returns the path to the XML file being processed, you can use the XPath 2.0 `base-uri()` or `document-uri()` functions to do the same.

Comment: you mean to say that there is no method exists in  saxon to retrieve the file name.

Comment: No, I said there are **two** methods to get it.