Create a new, filtered XML and add comment
What I have:

I have an OLD.XML file
I create ("copy") a NEW.XML which is nearly the same, but some nodes are filtered out / not copied

What do I use:
An XSLT with a base-template "xsl:copy" and a filter-template with "match.." (simplified example):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ili="http://www.interlis.ch/INTERLIS2.3">
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ili:GoAway"></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

What I'm looking for?
On the top of the XML I want to add a comment like
<!-- This file does not contain the elements GoAway -->
(or the luxury challenge):
<!-- This file is based on file SOURCENAME, and on CURRENTDATE the elements GoAway are filtered out-->
Is there a way to make it based on the xsl:copy command?
Thanks in advance for advice!

While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML with all relevant namespaces.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

"Is there a way to make it based on the xsl:copy command?" Not sure what you mean by that. The  xsl:copy command contains no information.

Re current date in XSLT 1.0 see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26628225/3016153.

Re filename see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9973011/17153010.

Adding a comment with fixed text is very easy (see @WolfgangSchinder's answer), but to include source and result filenames and the current date and time using XSLT 1.0 you will need to supply this information in the form of stylesheet parameters, for example
<xsl:param name="inputFile"/>
...
<xsl:comment>
  <xsl:value-of select="$inputFile"/>

The way you supply the parameters depends on the API you are using to invoke the transformation.
Like nearly everything else in XSLT-land, it becomes easier with later XSLT versions. XSLT 1.0 is a quarter of a century old!

You might try a stylesheet like this:
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ili="http://www.interlis.ch/INTERLIS2.3">
<xsl:template match="/">        
    <xsl:comment>
        <xsl:text>This file is based on file </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="base-uri(/)"/>
        <xsl:text>, and on </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="current-date()"/>
        <xsl:text> the elements GoAway are filtered out</xsl:text>
    </xsl:comment>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ili:GoAway"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>

The question is tagged xslt-1.0.

Hi,
based on your postings I found a way for the "simple solution" - it was as usual a "small", but important thing I messed up before. , The "luxury" solution is in the waiting loop for me - I should take a look at xslt-2.0 in the next time.
I'm aware that my knowledge is far below the average here and my questions are a little bit nebulous like "I have a dream to solve something", but I'm happy that nevertheless I find help here.
Thanks to you all!
